# Identity Server 3 does not return claims when calling userInfo

Tags: identityserver3, claims

We've got an identity server 3 set up to handle authentication / authorization and we cannot seem to get the service to return anything related to the scopes we supply.

We call authorize from an Angular application with the following scopes:

```js
scope: "openid profile email roles api",
```

and successfully returns an access_token.

Within the access_token, I can see that the scopes had been set correct, so my assumption here is that, supplying /userInfo with this access_token should return the profile, email and roles, but it's not.

The scopes have been set up, in the Identity Server hook in the Web API project, like this:

```cs
return new List<Scope>
{
    StandardScopes.OpenId,
    StandardScopes.Profile,
    StandardScopes.Email,
    StandardScopes.Roles,

    new Scope
    {
        Name = "api",
        DisplayName = "Api",
        Type = ScopeType.Resource,
        Emphasize = true,

        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
        {
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, true),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, true),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, true),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, true),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, true),
            new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.IssuedAt, true),
            new ScopeClaim(InoxicoClaimTypes.ClientAccount, true),
            new ScopeClaim(InoxicoClaimTypes.UserNumber, true),
        },
        ScopeSecrets = new List<Secret>
        {
            new Secret("...".Sha256())
        }
    }
};
```

and where we set up the client:

```cs
new Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientName = "Workflow",
    ClientId = "workflow",

    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowRememberConsent = false,

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api",
        Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
        Constants.StandardScopes.Roles,
        "roles",
        "email"
    },

    RedirectUris = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServer.Clients.Workflow.RedirectUris"] ?? string.Empty)
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .ToList(),

    AccessTokenLifetime = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServer.Clients.Workflow.AccessTokenLifetime"])*60,

    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>{ "*" },

    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,

    PostLogoutRedirectUris = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServer.Clients.Workflow.PostLogoutRedirectUris"] ?? string.Empty)
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .ToList(),

    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true
}
```

I'm not sure what we're missing here, since this should work out the box.

Comment: Can you try setting `IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true` on your "api" scope there? Also, we tend to use the "AlwaysInclude" variants of the static scopes, eg `StandardScopes.ProfileAlwaysInclude`, `StandardScopes.EmailAlwaysInclude`, etc.

Comment: Ahh, spotted the problem (I believe): your "api" scope is of type `ScopeType.Resource`. This scope is ignored when constructing the userinfo response. Change it to `ScopeType.Identity` and see what that does.

Comment: @CrescentFresh i'll have a look at that, thank you